# knockout js hides my html code

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

So i have done  "select option" when user select i need show some data in inputs and it works,but  only when i chose  any value  from select it shows my inputs,but i need always show my inputs,because i need  this inputs for another actions

**It is my select.**

```
 <select size="2" style="height: 200px;width: 200px" class="selection 
    data-bind="options:solutions, optionsText:'name',value:selectedSolutions"></select>
```

**It is inputs** which i must show always,they show only when i chose parameter  from select which above

```
<form class="col-md-5" data-bind="with: selectedSolutions" style="margin-left:128px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputsm">Solution Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="value:name" id="inputsm" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputdefault">Brief description:</label>
        <input class="form-control " style="height: 100px" data-bind="value:briefDescription" id="inputdefault" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="url">Read more:</label>
        <input class="form-control input-lg" data-bind="value:readMore" style="height:150px" data-bind="value:" id="url" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputlg">Solution manufacture URl:</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputlg" data-bind="value:manufactureUrl" type="text">
      </div>
    </form>
```

thanks for help and sorry for english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `with` binding, anything inside your `form` tag will not being shown unless `selectedSolutions` is not null.

I guess inside your ViewModel, you are initializing the `selectedSolutions` property like this `viewModel.selectedSolutions = ko.observable();`

So, you have to set a default value for `selectedSolutions` to make sure anything inside your `form` tag is always shown. Something likes below:

```
viewModel.selectedSolutions = ko.observable({
    name: "", // you could put any default value you want here, not just blank
    briefDescription: "",
    readMore: "",
    manufactureUrl: ""
});
```